# How to make TCPDF checkbox with pipe style?

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox, tcpdf

I tried with style, but not working..

Env: PHP

Now(Default Tcpdf STYLE):
https://prnt.sc/utdg8v

I want something like that:
https://prnt.sc/utdgwr

I can't use HTML/CSS(or Yes?). Because I have to put it in an existing PDF.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The static method getAnnotOptFromJsProp() which replaces what is typed with the appropriate one does not support the "style" property.
[image: Comment from method getAnnotOptFromJsProp()]

I used Java Script to change this value, although this may not always work.

```
$pdf->CheckBox('myCheckbox', 50, false, array(), array());

$js = <<<EOD
var f = this.getField("myCheckbox");
f.style = style.ch;
EOD;

$pdf->IncludeJS($js);
```

The list of styles is available in the documentation at this link on page 250.
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JS1.pdf